# Драйвер RAID под WINDOWS Server 2003

Tags: windows, raid

Где можно найти RAID драйвер на asus p5nd2-sli? Если не сложно, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Драйвера для данной материнской платы можно найти на http://support.asus.com/
Но в данный момент данный ресурс, к сожалению, недоступен. Надеюсь в понедельник починят.

Comment: Работает работает. Спасибо. :)

Comment: Ну и здорово, у меня все еще не работает.

Answer (score 0):

На [официальном сайте](http://ru.asus.com/product.aspx?P_ID=0N4fWKGe1CCsPDnW), в разделе загрузок.